# Multipart not working with Angular 4 HttpClient

Tags: java, angular, rest, spring-boot, ng2-file-upload

I have following code which uses HttpClient

```
/**
 * This method used to upload file on server with other details.
 * 
 * @param {FormData} formData - This parameter have data about keyId, KeyValue and docCatId
 * @param {string} url - This parameter contains serverside upload file Endpoint
 * @memberof DocumentUploadService
 */
uploadDocument(formData: FormData, url: string): Observable <DocumentUploadResponse> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data','Accept':'application/json','boundary':'simple-text'});
    return this.http.post<DocumentUploadResponse>(url, FormData,{headers: headers});

}
```

FormData object created like below

```
const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('docContent', fileList[0]);
        formData.append('documentUploadDetails', JSON.stringify(this.documentUpload));
        formData.append('docName',fileList[0].name);
```

Rest Service has written as mentioned below

```
@RequestMapping(headers = ("content-type=multipart/form-data;boundary=simple-text"),method=RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes=MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<DocumentUploadResponse> uploadDocument(
        @RequestParam(name = "docContent", required = true) MultipartFile multipartFile,
        @RequestParam(name = "documentUploadDetails", required = true) String documentUploadDetails,
        @RequestParam(name = "docName", required = true) String docName)
{   
    LOGGER.debug("Invoked uploadDocument method");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(documentUploadHandler.handleUploadDocument(multipartFile, documentUploadDetails,docName), HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

So when I upload any document I received error mentioned below

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:111) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1099) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_141]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_141]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]
```

I tried many combinations to pass content-type and removed content-type. Also tried to add some fields and removed header, but nothing worked in my case

Comment: `'boundry'`? Did you mean `'boundary'`

Comment: @JBNizet - Thanks man for noticing its typo while posting code on stackoverflow

Comment: @Pankaj Saboo - Have you resolved it in the end (or was the problem in the typo)? I am facing similar issue and I am really desperate - also tried many combinations with content-type and cannot get it working. Strange is that identical angular code was working, when we were using JAX-RS / CXF endpoint (now we are migrating to Spring @RestController).

Comment: @Michel Aron- Sorry for late reply. It didn't resolve so I changed HttpClient to deprecated HTTP class(from angular 2) that work fine.